# appending function include a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was reading the code below:

```
for i in range(pred_prob.shape[0]):
        correct_pred_prob.append(pred_prob[i, dev_labels[i]])
```

But I am not quite understand how can we append a list with two variable

```
pred_prob[i, dev_labels[I]]
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Because it isn't a list, it is a [`numpy.ndarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html).

Comment: Even if it wasn't a `numpy` array, the syntax `...[i, dev_lables[i]]` just means you are indexing something with a tuple `(i, dev_labels[i])`. Only the comma is used to define a tuple; the parentheses are optional in many contexts.

Comment: @chepner with the single exception of the empty tuple `()`, which cannot contain a comma.

Comment: @gilch Yes, but clearly the empty tuple is not relevant to this question.

Comment: @gilch Well, you are including all 0 commas there, and the parens are needed for disambiguation between the empty tuple and nothing at all. :)